# Pageable sorting problems with Spring JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm haccing an issue with Spring JPA regarding sorting and paginating. Currently I'm receiving this warning:

```
WARN [NamedQuery] (NamedQuery.java:65) - Finder method public abstract     org.springframework.data.domain.Page loc.starterkit.business.entities.application.repository.ApplicationRepository.findByNameLike(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable) 
is backed by a NamedQuery but contains a Pageable parameter! Sorting delivered via this Pageable will not be applied!
```

My JPA interface code looks like this:

```
public interface ApplicationRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Application,Long>{

Page<Application> findByNameLike(String name, Pageable pageable);
```

}

My entity factory configuration:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="loc.starterkit.business"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="general" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">${hibernate.connection.charSet}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">${hibernate.use_sql_comments}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_query_cache}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">${hibernate.cache.region.factory_class}</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I don't know why I cannot use sorting in pageable methods in this case . Any ideas?

EDIT:

My Application Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="APPLICATION")
public class Application {

@Id
@Column(name="ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Column(name="NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
private String description;

public Application() {
    super();
}

.... (getters and setters here)
```

}

Changing PagingAndSortingRepository to JPARepository seems to throw same warning. BUT, after some tests, I've found out that this WARN means nothing. Things seems to work nicely:

```
Hibernate: 
/* select
    count(*) 
from
    Application as generatedAlias0 
where
    generatedAlias0.name like :param0 */ select
        count(*) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        APPLICATION applicatio0_ 
    where
        applicatio0_.NAME like ?
Hibernate: 
/* select
    generatedAlias0 
from
    Application as generatedAlias0 
where
    generatedAlias0.name like :param0 
order by
    generatedAlias0.name asc */ select
        applicatio0_.ID as ID0_,
        applicatio0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT2_0_,
        applicatio0_.NAME as NAME0_ 
    from
        APPLICATION applicatio0_ 
    where
        applicatio0_.NAME like ? 
    order by
        applicatio0_.NAME asc limit ?
```

So I think that this WARN means nothing but I want to know why it's being issued

Comment: can you post your `Application` entity? also, why did you extend `PagingAndSortingRepository` instead of `JpaRepository` (which is an extension of `PagingAndSortingRepository`?

Comment: Encountered same issue any work around to this? how can you know the Pageable returns content / is empty?